# Generate Cycle Graph/Diagram using GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap, linear-groups

I recently looked into linear Groups such as the general and special linear group of finite fields. To get a better intuition for groups of that type, I wanted to look at cycle graphs for some of those groups. I already drew some cycle graphs for groups that have a small order. (6,24,48)

As you can imagine when the order gets bigger I don't want to draw them by Hand anymore. (when I say hand I mean LaTex/Tikz and some Haskell code).

So what I am asking is if there is a way to generate cycle graphs (adjacency list or image of drawn graph) with GAP or any other software.
(I know that GAP can generate Cayley graphs)

Comment: You may want to look at Group Explorer by by Nathan Carter and Ray Ellis: https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/. It does not work, I think, for an arbitrary group, but has a large collection for groups of small orders.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate" a graph? Construct an object that represents such a graph and lets you calculate its properties? Draw it on paper? Print it out in a particular format?

Comment: @ahulpke Either way, I would be happy with a graph image but an adjacency list or matrix wouldn't be a problem either.